# Copy merge specific worksheets to one workbook

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I am trying to copy a worksheet called "application" from all identical files in a folder, into a master workbook and rename the copied worksheet in the name of the file its been copied from. So far my code copies everything and I cannot get it to rename the copied worksheet to name of file it came from.

Thank you

```
 Sub GetSheets()
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Path = "C:\Users\Desktop\Work docs\"
     Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
     Do While Filename <> ""
         Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
         For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
             If Sheet.Name = "application" Then
             End If
             Sheets.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
         Next Sheet
         Workbooks(Filename).Close SaveChanges:=False
         Filename = Dir()
     Loop
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: What's with that indentation? Do it properly and your error will be obvious

Comment: Thanks Mark. I happen not to be an expert on VBA & have limited experience from reverse engineering codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **IF** condition is closing before you are copying 'application' sheet, so `Sheets.Copy` will just copy all the sheets from your workbook. You can try the below code:

```
Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path1 & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each Sheet In Workbooks(Filename).Sheets
        If Sheet.Name = "application" Then
            Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("application").Name = Filename & "-application"    'Changes the sheetname from "application" of test1.xls workbook to "test1.xls-application"
        End If
    Next Sheet
    Workbooks(Filename).Close SaveChanges:=False
    Filename = Dir()
Loop
```

I was not able to use **Path** as a variable (maybe due to some system configuration - need to check why), so I have used **Path1** instead. You can use `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets` also instead of `Workbooks(Filename).Sheets`. However I feel its better to reference a workbook by its name.

Comment: Fantastic this worked a treat and saved me hours. Thank you very much.